# Why does my CSS media query break the styling?

Tags: css, media-queries, fluid-layout

I'm trying to make my sidebar fluid so it adjusts with the browser window, and everything seems to be working great, except for the fact that with the media query added, my CSS styling breaks, but when I take the query away it is back to the norming styling from my stylesheet. Can someone look at my code and tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

BTW, when I add the second ending curly brace to the #rightandoverview media query, the styling go back to the way it should, but the fluidity doesn't work. What could it be?

```
#righthandoverview {
position: absolute;
top: 91px;
right: 0px;
width: 20%;
height:215px;
background-color: white;
webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px -5px #777;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px -5px #777;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 5px -5px #777;
}

@media screen and (max-width:830px) and (min-width:100px) {
#righthandoverview {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-top: 5px;

}





#righthandoverview ul {
position: absolute;
display: inline;
float: left;
font-family: klavika-light;
list-style-type: none;
text-decoration: none;
white-space: nowrap;
}

@media screen and (max-width:830px) and (min-width:100px) {
#righthandoverview ul {
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-top: 10px;

}
}




#righthandoverview ul li > a {
display: inline;
text-decoration: none;
color:#8BAFDA;
}   

#righthandoverview ul li {
padding-bottom: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing a bracket to end your first media query

```
@media screen and (max-width:830px) and (min-width:100px) {
#righthandoverview {
    float: left;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin-top: 5px;

}





#righthandoverview ul {
position: absolute;
display: inline;
float: left;
font-family: klavika-light;
list-style-type: none;
text-decoration: none;
white-space: nowrap;
}
}
```

Comment: There's an easy trick to find slightly off syntax like a missing bracket. I fed this into the CSS Validator (http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) and immediately got Parse Error" with a line number pointing to the error. (Many text editors highlight matching brackets too, in which case the lack of a highlight tells you where there's a problem.:-)

Answer (score 0):

you missed a bracket in the following code, i have added it.

```
 @media screen and (max-width:830px) and (min-width:100px) {
        #righthandoverview {
            float: left;
            width: 30%;
            background-color: yellow;
            margin-top: 5px;

        }
    }
```